# Mist Connection Error at Private Geth Node

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I've created my private network run my Geth Node as:

```
geth --datadir /mychaindata --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover
```

I can successfully attach it and create account when I run:

```
geth attach ipc:/mychaindata/geth.ipc
```

I've written a smart contract and I want to deploy it via Mist. I've downloaded Mist source code and switched to master branch, and compiled the source code. When I run this:

```
yarn dev:electron --rpc /mychaindata/geth.ipc
```

It successfully starts with an error at command line:

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ electron -r babel-register main.js --rpc /mychaindata/geth.ipc
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.381] [INFO] Settings - Running in production mode: false
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.416] [INFO] EthereumNode - undefined null 'fast'
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.417] [INFO] EthereumNode - Defaults loaded: geth main fast
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.548] [INFO] main - Starting in Mist mode
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.672] [INFO] Db - Loading db: /Users/kamaci/Library/Application Support/Electron/mist.lokidb
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.679] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.680] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
2018-01-01 16:19:26.703 Electron[93067:4305016] *** WARNING: Textured window <AtomNSWindow: 0x7ffbe3d9e170> is getting an implicitly transparent titlebar. This will break when linking against newer SDKs. Use NSWindow's -titlebarAppearsTransparent=YES instead.
[2018-01-01T16:19:26.864] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2018-01-01T16:19:29.413] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2018-01-01T16:19:29.422] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset
[2018-01-01T16:19:29.485] [ERROR] main - Couldn't infer if computer automatically syncs time. Error: checkEnabled is not supported on this operating system
    at Object.checkEnabled (/Users/kamaci/projects/mist/node_modules/os-timesync/index.js:97:30)
    at checkTimeSync (/Users/kamaci/projects/mist/main.js:218:18)
    at /Users/kamaci/projects/mist/main.js:170:5
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/kamaci/projects/mist/main.js:140:191)
    at /Users/kamaci/projects/mist/main.js:140:361
    at <anonymous>
[2018-01-01T16:19:29.893] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2018-01-01T16:19:29.894] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.247] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.247] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.247] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.248] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.248] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.249] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.269] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.269] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.270] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.274] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.396] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - Sanity check failed for Geth Error: Unable to find "1.7.2" in Geth output
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (/Users/kamaci/projects/mist/node_modules/ethereum-client-binaries/src/index.js:635:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.400] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"/Users/kamaci/eth/as1/mychaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.402] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.403] [INFO] NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.404] [INFO] NodeSync - Starting sync loop
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.405] [INFO] Sockets/4 - Connect to {"path":"/mychaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.405] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connect to {"path":"/mychaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.406] [INFO] main - Connected via IPC to node.
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.427] [INFO] Sockets/4 - Connected!
[2018-01-01T16:19:31.427] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connected!
[2018-01-01T16:19:32.086] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
```

Mist window is a white window:

[image: Window Window]

How can Mist connect to my private geth node?

Comment: i Stuck with same problem .do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting geth with below command worked for me

geth --datadir=./chaindata/ --rpc --ipcpath ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc console